# Contact synchronization slows down my phone and dialer

Tags: sync, phone-app

I am using Canvas Nitro A311.
The problem with the phone is that its contacts and dialer are always slow. Might be because of contact synchronization process of Gmail accounts. I, turn the auto sync OFF, from Account, but the dialer is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that particular phone, but on my phone when my dialer and contacts slow down ...I go into my apps and clear the cache on all of them. If you can get the 360 Security App it helps also. I hope that this helps you.